# Add a comma to the array but the last one.

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am currently using this method to add a comma to the elements in the array when I print it out to the user.

totalCity += totalCity + ", "

How do I make it add to all the elements in the array but the last one?

currently, if I have this

abc

it adds a,b,c,

I will like it to be a,b,c

Thanks for the help

Comment: use js Join. Include vanillaJS for that. It is easier 
<script src ="getfromair.vanilajs.min"></script>

Comment: @Jonasw Do as small research...

Comment: @Jonasw just google vanillaJS and comment after that. you are gonna like it. I assure you

Comment: @JinsPeter lol. youve tricked me... :0

Comment: lol.. Its fun na..

Answer (score 5):

```
["you","can","simply","join","them!"].join(", ");
```

Comment: Argh! beat me to it :P

Comment: @Purefan ;) it became one of my 10 best answers in a few seconds, while many of my really good answers never got any kind of feedback :/ weird world...

Comment: Yeah.. I clicked on comment.. to answer